# Can AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap ever return null?

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I'm trying to troubleshoot a `NullReferenceException` that's occuring on a production system. If the line number in the stack trace can be trusted, then it would seem to indicate that `AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` returned null:

```
this.jobRunner =
    (JobRunner)this.appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(assemblyName, typeName);
// ...

try
{
    this.jobRunner.Run(this.job); // <== NullReferenceException occurs here
}
```

However, [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c4f1xde.aspx) doesn't specifically say that null is a possible return value:

> **Return Value**
>
>   Type: System.Object
>   An instance of the object specified by *typeName*.

**My question:** Can `AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` legitimately return null? If so, what would that mean?

Comment: Any chance that this.jobRunner is being nullified somewhere in between?

Comment: @M.A.Hanin: No. I omitted only two statements: `this.status = Status.RunningJob; Monitor.Exit(this.syncLock);`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` can legitimately return null.

Here is the reflected code for the method (using .NET Reflector):

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
public object CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(string assemblyName, string typeName)
{
    ObjectHandle handle = this.CreateInstance(assemblyName, typeName);
    if (handle == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return handle.Unwrap();
}
```

Deeper we get:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
public ObjectHandle CreateInstance(string assemblyName, string typeName)
{
    if (this == null)
    {
        throw new NullReferenceException();
    }
    if (assemblyName == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("assemblyName");
    }
    return Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, typeName);
}
```

So the real question is: can `Activator.CreateInstance` legitimately return null. And the answer is **YES**, it can return null on certain conditions. One example I've found is creating nullable types (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691601/creating-a-nullable-object-via-activator-createinstance-returns-null)), but I'm sure there are other examples.

Comment: It makes sense that `Activator.CreateInstance` would return null when asked to construct a `Nullable<T>`, but in my case, the specified type is never a `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: I understand. I personally don't know why null is returned in your case at the production system, but the answer to your question is yes - it can return null. To diagnose your situation I'd suggest the usual techniques for production debugging - logging, tracing, production debuggers such as WinDbg, etc. Otherwise, show us some more code (like the JobRunner class)

Comment: @M.A.Hanin Good answer! By the way, the .NET Fx source is shared. You can download it from http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx