# How to create an instance of a Nullable<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection

Suppose we have two classes:

```
public class ParentEntity
{
    public ChildEntity Child { get; set; }
}

public class ChildEntity
{
    public byte? NullableValue { get; set; }
    public byte Value { get; set; }
}
```

The task is to express the following code in linq expressions:

```
parent.Child == null ? null : parent.Child.NullableValue
```

To do that I tried to use the following code:

```
public static Expression GetCondition<TParent, TChild, TChildKey>(
                              Expression<Func<TParent, TChild>> pe, 
                              Expression<Func<TChild, TChildKey>> ce)
{
    var test = Expression.Equal(pe.Body, Expression.Constant(null));

    var ifTrue = Expression.Constant(Activator.CreateInstance<TChildKey>());
    var ifFalse = Expression.Property(pe.Body, 
                                      (ce.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name);
    return Expression.Condition(test, ifTrue, ifFalse);
}
```

Running this code with

```
Expression<Func<ParentEntity, ChildEntity>> pe = n => n.Child;    

GetCondition(pe, n => n.Value);         // ok
GetCondition(pe, n => n.NullableValue); // throws an ArgumentException
```

throws an `ArgumentException` at the last line (at the return statement in the `GetCondition`), saying that the types of arguments are mismatched.

Having analysed this code I found out that `Activator.CreateInstance<TChildKey>()` returns `object`, but not `TChildKey`, when `TChildKey` is `System.Nullable<T>`, i.e. `ifTrue.Type` is `object`, while I expected it to be `System.Nullable<byte>`.

This very issue is discussed in [SO: Creating a nullable object via Activator.CreateInstance returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691601/creating-a-nullable-object-via-activator-createinstance-returns-null) pointing to [Reflection and Nullable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haibo_luo/archive/2005/08/23/455241.aspx)

But none of these suggests anything to solve the issue.

Is there a way to create an instance of exactly `System.Nullable<T>` type, having value `null`?
Or maybe there is some other way to express the original conditional expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try `Expression.New`:

```
var ifTrue = Expression.New(typeof(Nullable<int>));
```

Comment: Where could one read in deep about such peculiarities, I wonder!?

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you

```
    public static Expression GetCondition<TParent, TChild, TChildKey>(
                          Expression<Func<TParent, TChild>> pe,
                          Expression<Func<TChild, TChildKey>> ce)
    {
        var test = Expression.Equal(pe.Body, Expression.Constant(null));

        ConstantExpression ifTrue;
        Type type = typeof(TChildKey);
        // check if it is a nullable type
        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (Nullable<>))
        {
            ifTrue = Expression.Constant(default(TChildKey));
        }
        else
        {
            ifTrue = Expression.Constant(   Activator.CreateInstance<TChildKey>());
        }

        var ifFalse = Expression.Property(pe.Body, (ce.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name);

        return Expression.Condition(test, ifFalse, ifFalse);
    }
```

Comment: This will not work either as `ifTrue.Type` will still be `Object` for `default(TChildKey)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to explicitly specify what type of constant is being created by `Expression.Constant` using the two parameter function overload.

```
var ifTrue = Expression.Constant(Activator.CreateInstance<TChildKey>(), typeof(TChildKey));
```

`Nullable<>` requires some very careful handling, particularly around nulls. Being explicit is helpful and often necessary when doing anything outside the norm.