# Get Values from Dynamic Property

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a project that makes extensive use of XML config files, and I would like to take a few things to the next level with generic implementation of shared code.

Problem is, of my five classes, two handle a "description" grid view differently.
This grid view shows objects of the appropriate type with various columns.

Also of note: the data is passed via a Data Record, so the GUI does not have direct access to the source object(s).

Here is my current "attempt" to get dynamic data, using a rather silly hack (that did not work)

```
GetObjectData( MyClass myObject, string[] dataToGet)
{
    List<string> dataToReturn = new List<string>();
    foreach (string propertyName in dataToGet)
    {
       try
       {
         Label tempLabel = new Label();
         tempLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", myObject, propertyName);

         dataToReturn.Add(tempLabel.Text);
       }
       catch { dataToReturn.Add(""); }
    }
}
```

There MUST be a way to do this, but I'm not sure what it would be called, or how to approach the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Reflection to get property value in this manner:

```
public void GetObjectData(MyClass myObject, string[] dataToGet) 
       {    
           List<string> dataToReturn = new List<string>();

           Type type = myObject.GetType(); 

           foreach (string propertyName in dataToGet)     
           {        
               try        
               {
                   PropertyInfo pInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
                   var myValue = pInfo.GetValue(myObject, null); 
                   dataToReturn.Add(Convert.ToString(myValue));        
               }       
               catch 
               { dataToReturn.Add("");
               }    
           } 
       }
```

Hope this help you.. you can use `dictionay` to save your return rather than list of string.

For Reference:
[Use reflection to get the value of a property by name in a class instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430944/use-reflection-to-get-the-value-of-a-property-by-name-in-a-class-instance)
[Set property Nullable<> by reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488706/set-property-nullable-by-reflection)
[Reflection - get attribute name and value on property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637679/reflection-get-attribute-name-and-value-on-property)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Perfect!  Works like a charm  :)

Answer (score 1):

you could also use the dynamic type if you are using .net framework 4

```
   public void GetObjectData(dynamic myObject, string[] dataToGet) 
   {    
       List<string> dataToReturn = new List<string>();

       foreach (string propertyName in dataToGet)     
       {        
           try        
           {
               dataToReturn.Add(Convert.ToString(myObject.propertyName));        
           }       
           catch 
           { dataToReturn.Add("");
           }    
       } 
   }
```

Comment: This does not seem to work... the compiler thinks '.propertyName' is a compile-time value.  Notably, using '."foo" ' does not work either.