# Generic Method to convert datatable to list

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I'm using below code:

```
 public static List<T> ConvertToList1<T>(DataTable dt)
        {
            var columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                    .Select(c => c.ColumnName)
                    .ToList();
            var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            return dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
            {
                T objT1 = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                foreach (var pro in properties)
                {
                    if (columnNames.Contains(pro.Name))
                    {
                        PropertyInfo? pI = objT.GetType().GetProperty(pro.Name);
                        pro.SetValue(objT, row[pro.Name] == DBNull.Value ? null : Convert.ChangeType(row[pro.Name], pI.PropertyType));

                    }
                }
                return objT1;
            }).ToList();
        }
```

But I'm getting error for decimal field having null values.

**Invalid cast from 'System.Decimal' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Decimal, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral**

```
 public class SampleModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string? Code { get; set; } = null!;
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public decimal? Quantity1 { get; set; }
        public decimal? Quantity2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set property Nullable<> by reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488706/set-property-nullable-by-reflection)

Comment: I would use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3531824/2557128).

Answer (score 1):

Um, reading again... You mean that a non-null decimal value in the row cannot be assigned to a nullable decimal? Or did you mean a dbnull that cannot be assigned to the nullable decimal?

---

You can use the [`DataRow.IsNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.isnull?view=net-6.0) to check if the value is dbnull. In that case you just skip it as the nullable already has default null.

```
// <CODE SNIP />

if (columnNames.Contains(pro.Name))
{
    // if the value was null, just skip it.
    if(!row.IsNull(pro.Name))
    {
        PropertyInfo? pI = objT.GetType().GetProperty(pro.Name);
        pro.SetValue(objT, Convert.ChangeType(row[pro.Name], pI.PropertyType));
    }
}
```

Comment: The former - `Convert.ChangeType` fails to convert `decimal` to `decimal?`. `null` is not involved in the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a play.
The link from @Ryan Wilson was very useful.

In short, where you have a nullable type, you want to cast to the underlying type.  Consider:

```
decimal? target;
decimal source = 42;
target = source;
```

This is perfectly reasonable code.  We can assign a `decimal` value to a `decimal?` variable.

Using `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(myType)` returns a type or null if `myType` is not nullable.  Extending the above snippet:

```
var underlying1 = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(target.GetType());
var underlying2 = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(source.GetType());
```

Here, `underlying2` is `null`, and `underlying1` is `decimal`.

To put this into practice, then, we slightly alter the innermost part of your conversion method to become:

```
PropertyInfo pI = objT1.GetType().GetProperty(pro.Name);
var targetType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pI.PropertyType) ?? pI.PropertyType;
pro.SetValue(objT1, row[pro.Name] == DBNull.Value 
  ? null
  : Convert.ChangeType(row[pro.Name], targetType));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
       public static List<SampleModel> ConvertToList1<T>(DataTable dt)
        {
            List<SampleModel> results = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new SampleModel()
            {
                Id = x.Field<Guid>("Id"),
                ProjectId = x.Field<Guid>("ProjectId"),
                Code = x.Field<string>("Code"),
                Description = x.Field<string>("Description"),
                Quantity1 = x.Field<decimal>("Quantity1"),
                Quantity2 = x.Field<decimal>("Quantity1")
            }).ToList();


            return results;
        }
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the purpose of `ConvertToList1`...